# element direction control with css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I have 3 birds with css animation.Currently all three birds are coming inside the canvas in a straight line but birds don't fly like this.What I want to achieve is clearly described in the picture.I want to control the flying directions of the bird in every phase of their travel in to the canvas. Can anyone help me to achieve it please?

[image: Flying Direction]

[image: Result after coming in to the canvas]

**My Code**

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="canvas">
    <img class="people" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/9967e45cc8.png" alt="">
    <img class="bird-1" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/996ac926a0.png" alt="">
    <img class="bird-2" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/996bc03236.png" alt="">
    <img class="bird-3" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/996cfb24a4.png" alt="">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
margin: 0;
}

.canvas{
background-color: lightgrey;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
position: relative;
left: 30%;
top: 20%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.logo,
.people{
 position: absolute;
}


.bird-1{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
-webkit-animation: first 2s linear forwards;
animation: first 2s linear forwards;
top: -70px;
left: 55px;
}

.bird-2{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
-webkit-animation: second 2s linear forwards;
animation: second 2s linear forwards;
top: 165px;
left: -50px;
}
.bird-3{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
-webkit-animation: third 2s linear forwards;
animation: third 2s linear forwards;
top: 163px;
right: -50px;
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes first{
0%{top: -70px;}
100%{top:65px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes second{
0%{left: -50px;}
100%{left:15px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes third{
0%{right: -50px;}
100%{right:135px;}
}
```

[My PEN](http://codepen.io/audhit/pen/BWKEVE)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a movement on X axis at a certain speed (with curve), and a Y axis movement at another speed. You can check this tutorial, it should give you everything you need to do it in CSS:
http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/curved-path-animations-in-css/

You can also create a SVG path for each bird and use this technique, but it needs JavaScript: http://icanbecreative.com/article/animate-element-along-svg-path/

Comment: thanks Zetura, I will get back to you once I try it :) .. cheers